# Saving image to photo album works on iPhone but crashes on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, photo

I am using the below code to save an image to the photo album:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);
```

This code works on an iPhone but crashes on an iPad. Why might this happen?

Comment: How about providing the exact error message, and showing one line of code isn't going to help much either.

Comment: Welcome to SO. @l'L'l is right, you should edit your question to add more data like the error you are getting. Are you using a UIImage or a UIImageView. If it is a UIImageView, you should be using imageToSave.image

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailImageViewController addPictureSaved:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c39780'

Comment: The first line of code I posted is what is in the "addPictureSaved:" method. As I said it works on the iPhone but not on the iPad? Thank you.

Comment: - (IBAction)addPictureSaved {
    
     // Save it to the camera roll / saved photo album
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.imageView.image, self, nil, nil);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Image Saved" message:@"The image has been saved to your Camera Roll." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}

Comment: I solved it. The problem was that I had changed the method name and had not linked the storyboard button to the new method. Sorry.